# Solr Stopwords are not getting removed

Tags: solr, stop-words

Im using the schema and the field as below, but once the documents are index the stopwords are not removed from the documents

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Field

```
 <field name="ad_title" type="text_en"/>
```

But still the stopwords are not removed from the title

Stopwordlist

```
# Standard english stop words taken from Lucene's StopAnalyzer
a
an
and
are
as
at
be
but
by
for
if
in
into
is
it
no
not
of
```

Sample Title that is available in the documents

```
"ad_title":"Aluminum Foil And Baking Paper Rewinding Machine",
```

Comment: When you say they are not removed - how are you testing that they're being removed? What's the content of `stopwords.txt`?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have updated the description

Comment: The stored text will not be changed. Stopwords only affect the stored _tokens_ generated from the document. The text returned for the field will not change in any way from an analysis chain. You can use the Analysis page under Solr's admin interface to see which tokens _do_ get generated from the input text (and if you look at that, the `and` terms is probably dropped).

Comment: Brother, as said above, stop words only affects in index tokens not stored text. You can check each field conversion pipeline from "Analysis" tab in Solr admin.

Answer (score 0):

As commented, you should test each field from Analysis option in Solr admin dashboard. Both for query as well as index options. A sample snippet is as follows

[image]

First select corresponding field and then write a sample query in search bar.